# Eventviewer eventid for automatic user account unlock

Tags: windows, event-viewer

Trying to figure out if there is an event written to the security log after user account was **automatically** unlocked. Already found out that manual unlock generating 4767 in security log, the question is if for automatic unlock any event generated? and if so, what gpo should be defined to see it by default in the log.

Comment: What is an "automatic unlock"?

Comment: AD group policy when account unlocked by itself after x minutes